# Changing HTML button font with CSS

Tags: html, css, button

I've been trying and failing to change button font with CSS. I can change their background color and I can change a textarea input's font, but for some reason I don't seem to be able to change a button's font. From my limited understanding, the following code should work:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
    body {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    input[type=button] {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    </style> 
</head>
<body> 
    This is a button: 
    <input type = "button" value = "Please click"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

But only changes the font of the text, not the button. What am I missing?

[UPDATE] Per the responses here I changed `input [type = button]` to `input[type=button]`.

Comment: `input [type = button]` != `input[type = button]`

Comment: Okay, so I removed the spaces. If I add a change such as color before the font change, it works, but if the only change is font-family it doesn't do anything. Could anyone enlighten me on way that is?

Comment: In your case only the space between `input` and `[` was important. And it works fine (see https://jsfiddle.net/vrpoL7bh/)

Comment: Hmm, the fiddle example shows up correctly on my phone but in every browser on my computer the button text remains unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same issue in the fiddle. If I change other elements, such as the background and text color, the font shows up correctly. If I only change the font, the browsers not displaying it correctly. Issue on my end?

Comment: Just add `appearance: none;` to the button's css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is so simple, you already have it. I think you made a mistake while writing CSS of it, you have a space in `input[type=button]`, though you were pretty close.

```
<style> 
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}
input[type=button] {
    font-family: monospace;

}
</style>
```

Comment: @sam this was work for me

Answer (score 2):

You have a spce between `input` and `[type=button]`. Remove it and it would work. Try this code.

```
 input[type=button] {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space after input. this should work:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<style> 
    body {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    input[type = button] {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    </style> 
</head>
<body> 
    This is a button: 
    <input type = "button" class = "button" value = "Please click"> 
</body> 
</html>
```